# ModemManager - Access Technology vs ModemCapability

Tags: linux, gsm, lte, umts

The device I am using has a Cinterion® EXS82-W built-in and I am noticing some weird behavior when it comes to *Access Technologies* and *ModemCapatibiliy*, IMHO it doesn't make sense, but I guess I am wrong somewhere and would like to know where.

##### Reading the *AccessTechnologies* property

```
busctl get-property org.freedesktop.ModemManager1 /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem AccessTechnologies
u 16384
```

The value 16384 should correspond to [MM_MODEM_ACCESS_TECHNOLOGY_LTE](https://github.com/linux-mobile-broadband/ModemManager/blob/1.18.8/include/ModemManager-enums.h#L236).

##### Reading the *SupportedCapabilities* property

```
busctl get-property org.freedesktop.ModemManager1 /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem SupportedCapabilities
au 1 4
```

The value should correspond to [MM_MODEM_CAPABILITY_GSM_UMTS](https://github.com/linux-mobile-broadband/ModemManager/blob/1.18.8/include/ModemManager-enums.h#L52).

##### Question

How can it be that my modem supports only GSM/UMTS from the general access technology families, but at the same time it is using the LTE technology when registered with or connected to a network?

Thanks and cheers.